# Celery chain, how to wait for dynamically created subtasks (seems to rule out chord)

Tags: python, celery

I have a series of tasks which should be executed sequentially for data integrity purposes. I don't need any kind of celery orchestration for this as such; I could just have one task do the top level steps sequentially.

This is in django, python 3.11 and latest celery. Redis is the broker and result store.

Some of these tasks use slow APIs to fetch pages. Each page triggers processing and many database writes. These writes themselves are slow due to their number, so to be faster in the wall clock sense, I want to offload each page of API processing to a subtask as soon as a page arrives from the API. For that, I can create a subtask. I create them "on the fly".

Much of celery orchestration shows that you prepare task signatures in advance, and then dispatch them. This pattern doesn't save me any wall clock time.

I want to make sure all the background database write subtasks finish before proceeding with the next top-level task.

I hoped that if I used chain (with immutable signatures) for the top level task, I could use the "add_to_parent" argument of .apply_async()  to somehow associate the dynmamic subtasks with their parent task. But it does not work. Documentation says it defaults to True, but I am setting it anyway.

Possibly I misunderstand what "add_to_parent" means, or possibly I am not implementing it correctly.

If the top level tasks is `@task api_1()`, the code structure is
`@task api_1() -> intermediate_function() -> @task write_database_page()` via `apply_async()`

I wonder how the sub task `write_database_page()` knows what its parent is, so I suspect and hope that this is my problem, and that I miss some way of making the parent task context known to the subtask.

There are many questions which seem similar, and the solution is to use chord().
However, I don't think there is any way of adding tasks to a chord() after the fact. It seems to be that chord() requires me to gather all the database write tasks before starting it.

An alternative is to somehow collect all the task IDs from the subtasks, and pass them to the next top level function, which would then somehow wait with a non blocking approach for them to complete. It surprises me that the pattern I want is not handled by Celery, and it seems more likely that I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

celery doesn't help with this with its orchestration. Using add_to_parent (which is default) does correctly show the parent/child relationship in redis, but celery can't or doesn't modify tasks which have already been sent to a worker. groups, chains and chords only work with the task signatures which exist at the the time they are created. For tasks to be blocked due to the new dependencies which didn't exist when the chain or chord was created, celery would potentially need to change a job which may already be sent to a worker, that is, only dependencies known when the task is scheduled can be used.

Instead, this requirements needs to be done manually; one solution is a loop which waits for subtasks to complete.

For example, this is code which directly adds three new tasks, and adds two more via an intermediary function

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def task_dummy_task1(self, part_number: int, job_id: int = None):
    job, job_id = JobMaster.get_job(job_id, job_title="dummy task")
    sleeping_duration = 5
    subtask_ids = []
    job.log_message(log_message=f"Entered dummy task 1 with sleeping duration of {sleeping_duration}")

    job.log_message(log_message="In dummy task1, creating subtask a")
    subtask = task_dummy_subtask.apply_async(kwargs={"parent_task_name": "task1_a", "job_id": job_id},
                                             add_to_parent=True)
    subtask_ids.append(subtask.id)
    job.log_message(log_message="In dummy task1, creating subtask b")

    subtask = task_dummy_subtask.apply_async(kwargs={"parent_task_name": "task1_b", "job_id": job_id},
                                             add_to_parent=True)
    subtask_ids.append(subtask.id)
    job.log_message(log_message="In dummy task1, creating subtask c")

    subtask = task_dummy_subtask.apply_async(kwargs={"parent_task_name": "task1_c", "job_id": job_id},
                                             add_to_parent=True)
    subtask_ids.append(subtask.id)
    sleeping_duration = 5

    job.log_message(log_message="In dummy task1, creating intermediary subtask d")
    subtask = intermediary_dummy_subtask_function(parent_task_name="task1_d", job_id=job_id)
    subtask_ids.append(subtask.id)
    job.log_message(log_message="In dummy task1, creating intermediary subtask e")
    subtask = intermediary_dummy_subtask_function(parent_task_name="task1_e", job_id=job_id)
    subtask_ids.append(subtask.id)

    time.sleep(sleeping_duration)
    # wait for subtasks to complete
    wait_for_tasks_to_complete(async_ids=subtask_ids, job_id=job_id,
                                    msg="Waiting in dummy task1 for subtasks to complete")

    job.log_message(log_message="Finished dummy task1 main body")

    return part_number
```

...

```
def wait_for_tasks_to_complete(async_ids: List[str], job_id: int = None, msg: str = None, timeout: int = 300):
    job, job_id = JobMaster.get_job(job_id, job_title="waiting for refresh data")
    job.log_message(log_message=f"Waiting for {len(async_ids)} tasks to complete, {msg}", status=consts.IN_PROGRESS,
                    job_score=0)
    job.log_message(log_message=f"tasks: {async_ids}", status=consts.IN_PROGRESS, job_score=0)

    all_success = True
    count_down = timeout
    while count_down > 0:
        for async_id in async_ids:
            result = app.AsyncResult(async_id)  # type:AsyncResult
            status = result.status
            if status == "SUCCESS":
                returned_value = result.result
                job.log_message(log_message=f"Confirmed status SUCCESS with {returned_value=}")
                # remove successful task from list
                async_ids.remove(async_id)
            else:
                all_success = False
                pass

        if all_success or len(async_ids) == 0:
            job.log_message(log_message="Finished waiting for refresh data, all tasks succeeded",
                            status=consts.COMPLETED, job_score=100)
            return
        count_down -= 1
        job.log_message(log_message=f"There are {len(async_ids)} tasks remaining")
        time.sleep(1)
    job.log_message(log_message="After waiting for {timeout=}, some tasks did not complete on time", status=consts.ERRORS_FOUND,
                    job_score=100)
```

...
intermediary function is :

```
def intermediary_dummy_subtask_function(parent_task_name, job_id)->AsyncResult:
    job, job_id = JobMaster.get_job(job_id, job_title="dummy task")
    job.log_message(
        log_message=f"Intermediary function for {parent_task_name} has been reached, will now make a task")
    r = task_dummy_subtask.apply_async(kwargs={"parent_task_name": parent_task_name, "job_id": job_id},
                                       add_to_parent=True)
    return r
```